# How to tell GitLab not to wait for sub process when remotly running sh script?

Tags: ssh, gitlab, subprocess, pipeline

I use a GitLab pipeline to

**a)** stop a python process on a remote server

**b)** deploy a new version of python code

**c)** trigger the restart of a python process (and do not wait for it to finish)

I have issues with the last step *c)*.

The job for *a)* works without issues and immediately finishes. Therefore, there does not seem to be a general issue with remote execution of *.sh scripts using `ssh` in GitLab pipelines.

The job for `c)` does start the python process and the helper script that I use for it seems to have been finished. **However, the GitLab job is stuck and keeps waiting after running the remote script.**

Here is the **ssh command** used for job *c)* in my `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
ssh -p 222 user@project.my-server.de ./path/to/start_server.sh
```

Content of the **remote script** `start_server.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -xv

cd my_directory
# Installs python dependencies
# The grep part removes "already satisfied" messages from the pip3 install output
pip3 install -r requirements.txt  | grep -v 'already satisfied'
cd src
(
tmux -c "python3 main.py > /dev/null" # starts server in background task to keep it open after script finished
) &
```

At the end of the output of the GitLab job I see three dots `...` denoting, that the job keeps running:

[image]

=> How can I correctly tell GitLab and/or ssh to

- not wait for sub processes
- not wait for console output of sub processes

**I tried several approaches that did not help:**

a) Add `&` at end of line:

```
ssh -p 222 user@project.my-server.de ./path/to/start_server.sh &
```

b) Use `nohup` command:

```
nohup ssh -p 222 user@project.my-server.de ./path/to/start_server.sh
```

or

```
ssh -p 222 user@project.my-server.de nohup ./path/to/start_server.sh
```

or in `start_server.sh`:

```
nohup python3 main.py &
```

c) Include extra `bash` command :

```
ssh -p 222 user@project.my-server.de bash ./path/to/start_server.sh
```

d) Use `-t` option:

```
ssh -p 222 -t user@project.my-server.de ./path/to/start_server.sh
```

e) Update gitlab-runner to current version 15.9.1

f) Enable Gitlab debug trace

```
job_back_start:
  variables:
    CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true"
```

Related:

https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-com-runner-never-finishes-after-script-is-completed/63817

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4025

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1979

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1962

https://serverfault.com/questions/962452/how-to-use-nohup-properly-within-an-ssh-session-invoked-by-gitlab-runner

**Edit**:

If I include the verbose option `-v` the job finishes sometimes. However, it still takes > 1 minute, mostly waiting after the script has already been executed:

ssh -p 222 -v user@project.my-server.de ./path/to/start_server.sh

[image]

...

[image]

The waiting step, that I would like to avoid, takes place between lines 107 and 108 of the output, after **I already got the return value**:

[image]

Comment: What happened when you tried the `nohup` option? That would likely the the path I would try first.  It does look like you're running nohup on the whole SSH call (as opposed to having ssh invoke nohup on the remote system).

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the position of nohup does not help: ssh -p 222 user@project.my-server.de nohup ./path/to/start_server.sh   The pipeline is still waiting after exit-status reply 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**a)** I got it working using the `at` command:

```
ssh -p 222 user@project.my-server.de "at now < ./path/to/start_server.sh"
```

Also see related question

https://serverfault.com/questions/962452/how-to-use-nohup-properly-within-an-ssh-session-invoked-by-gitlab-runner

**b)** What also worked was to wait a few seconds and kill the ssh process:

```
 - ssh -p 222 user@project.my-server.de ./path/to/start_server.sh &
 - sleep 5
 - pkill ssh
```

**c)** The content of the start_server.sh script can be simplified to

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -xv

cd my_directory
# Installs python dependencies
# The grep part removes "already satisfied" messages from the pip3 install output
pip3 install -r requirements.txt  | grep -v 'already satisfied'
cd src
python3 main.py
```